# How to strip seemingly unnecessary zeroes generated by gas?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to make a truly minimal shared "library" that has the least possible size it can be:

```
.text

.globl test
test:
        movb $1, %al
        movb $1, %dil
        movabs $message, %rsi
        movb $7, %dl
        syscall
        ret
message:
        .ascii "hello"
```

compiling with: `gcc -o test.so -fPIC -shared -m64 -nostdlib -s -O3 test.s`

And the output is still relatively huge: 4.8KB!!
When I look into the binary with radare I can see that after the .text section there are LOTS AND LOTS of seemingly unnecessary code caves produced my gas.

```
     ;-- section_end..rela.dyn:
            ;-- section..text:
            ;-- test:
/ (fcn) entry0 20
|   entry0 ();
|           0x00000268      b001           mov al, 1                   ; [6] va=0x00000268 pa=0x00000268 sz=25 vsz=25 rwx=--r-x .text
|           0x0000026a      40b701         mov dil, 1
|           0x0000026d      48be7c020000.  movabs rsi, 0x27c           ; "hello"  ; RELOC 64 
|           0x00000277      b207           mov dl, 7
|           0x00000279      0f05           syscall
\           0x0000027b      c3             ret
            ; DATA XREF from 0x0000026d (entry0)
            0x0000027c      68656c6c6f     push 0x6f6c6c65
            ;-- section_end..text:
            0x00000281      0000           add byte [rax], al
            0x00000283      0000           add byte [rax], al
            0x00000285      0000           add byte [rax], al
            ;-- section..eh_frame:
            ;-- section_end..eh_frame:
            ;-- section_end.LOAD0:
            0x00000287  ~   0000           add byte [rax], al
            0x00000289      0000           add byte [rax], al
            0x0000028b      0000           add byte [rax], al
            0x0000028d      0000           add byte [rax], al
            0x0000028f      0000           add byte [rax], al
            0x00000291      0000           add byte [rax], al
            ............ and so on, wasting lots of kilobytes......
```

What are these for, and how can I get rid of them (If I can/shall)?

Comment: Might depend on toolchain versions, for me it's 1864 bytes.  Using `lea message(%rip),%rsi` and `-Wl,--build-id=none` makes it even smaller. In general it makes little sense to go under 4k anyway. You might be able to remove some other sections using `objcopy` or compiler flags.

Comment: could you please tell me more about these compiler flags?

Comment: I've already done objcopy, but only can remove eh_frame, removing any other sections will result in a calling error of the exported function and/or segfaults

Comment: Most likely, this is padding added for optimization and/or binary-compatibility purposes. Why do you need to get rid of it? What is the motivation for making the code smaller?

Comment: Maximalism, I was taught to write code that is super fast and super small even if it looses portability this way. People nowadays do the opposite, multiplatform sluggish GC overhead hell :D